# What does the MDX error "Function expects a tuple set expression" mean?

Tags: mdx

I am trying to create a set using MDX that contains a CASE statement.  I am recieving an error i cannot seem to get around. The error is:  **The  function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.**
There are only two members that could be returned, and they are 'Daily' and 'MonthEnd'.  I appreciate any help you can provide.  At first i thought the error meant i needed to use the {} to create a set, but that is not making since to me, and i do not know where they would need to be added.

```
    CREATE SET [BDW Report Prototype].[MyDimension] AS 
    CASE [Grain].[Grain Dim ID]
     WHEN [Grain].[Grain Dim ID].&[1] THEN '1'
     WHEN [Grain].[Grain Dim ID].&[2] THEN '2'
    ELSE '3'
    END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the set you're creating must a valid set (that is an ordered list of tuples) MDX expression. But you're assigning to this set a string. You're basically writing:

```
CREATE SET [BDW Report Prototype].[MyDimension] AS '1'
```

Obviously your [MyDimension] set is not a set but a string.

What do you want to create?

Comment: That makes since.  Although i am new to this so i here goes.  I am trying to create a set, but perhaps that is not what i need.  I want to create 'something' that will filter the dimension data based on a set of statements.  The above example was just a segment of it, i was starting with.  I would like to be able to pull over an item that can be added like a where clause, that filters the data that is shown.

Comment: Understood. I guess it is worth a separate question (do not forget to accept this response ;-))  where you explain what you'd like to do in MDX to avoid confusion and to keep this question about the error message meaning.